# Color/drawable changes are applied to all views with the same background (color) [Marshmallow]

Tags: android

I've recently updated my phone to Android Marshmallow and ran my existing app on it, but noticed a difference in color behavior: When applying changes to the background of a view (drawable), all views that share the same background (reference) will also the same changes applied. While previously, this was not the case.

**Example**
In this example, I have a two views with the same background color, and I want to change the alpha level of one of both views.

First we define the views in the layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/testColor2">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/testColor1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Both views share the same background color or drawable:

```
<color name="testColor1">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="testColor2">#3F51B5</color>
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Now we are going to change one of the two background, like this:

```
    LinearLayout test1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test1);
    LinearLayout test2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test2);
    test1.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
```

Which results in this:
[image]

However, the desired and expected result is obviously this:
[image]

<strike>Download the sample project [here.](http://www46.zippyshare.com/v/lldNAdUs/file.html)</strike>

**A few thoughs:**

- When setting the Alpha level trough XML, this behavior does not apply.
- It does not matter if both views refer to a different color definition in colors.xml (like in the example), refer to the same color definition of both have the same color (hex) directly in the view's xml file.

**Question**
How can I make changes to a view's background without this affecting other views that share the same background. *Preferably while still being able to use a background that directly refers to a color defined in the color's xml file*

Comment: "and duplicating it to a drawable" -- what do you mean by this? Have you [used `mutate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate%28%29)?

Comment: I used: getConstantState().newDrawable();

Comment: Can you dump out the class of each view's background and constantstate, and check if they're the same object? It seems as if the two color resources have been "merged" somewhere -- meaning they have shared ConstantState. Maybe in the Resources class' caching? I would've expected them to stay separate since they're different resources (albeit with the same color value), but apparently not.

Comment: Anyway, the [ColorDrawable's state stores alpha](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.java#ColorState), so any changes to one will change the others. However, a call to [mutate()](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.java#mutate), like @CommonsWare recommended, should separate the drawables (by making a copy of the state).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Most likely the class of each view's background and constantstate are
> the same object. It seems as if the two color resources have been
> "merged" somewhere -- meaning they have shared ConstantState. Maybe in
> the Resources class' caching? I would've expected them to stay
> separate since they're different resources (albeit with the same color
> value), but apparently not.
>
> – [Snild Dolkow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4811803/snild-dolkow)

The ColorDrawable's state stores alpha, so any changes to one will change the others. To prevent this, you can first call mutate() on the drawable, separating the two drawables (by making a copy of the state).

In the example, this would result in using `test1.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(80);` instead of directly applying the alpha.

Comment: This seems to be the only post about this on SO.  After searching for a solution all over, I was going to finally ask about it myself. And then the SO prompt `"Did you try these links"` finally pointed me here.  Thanks very much!  - it saved my day :)

Comment: @gnB There is a very good article about this from Google itself. Link https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html

Comment: Finally, this shed some light. Thanks!