# Java/Android get.Background() setting alpha to all instances of drawable?

Tags: android, view, background, drawable, alpha

I have drawables and call them by setting android:background/foreground etc. and by .getBackground()

I don't want to have to make another whole set of images for this.

I'm trying to set the alpha for one Views background and have the Alpha remain at 255 for the other. But when I set the alpha using .getBackground().setAlpha() on one, it changes every instance of that drawable till it is set back. I'm also having an issue with setting the background to multiple views and it stretches the original into oblivion.

Anyone run into these kinds of issues, how did you solve them and is there a way to programmatically solve this without copying a set of images? I'm trying to keep this as lightweight as possible. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354788/color-drawable-changes-are-applied-to-all-views-with-the-same-background-color

Comment: Much obliged, I spent 2 or 3 days trying to wrap my head around this and here you are! My savior! Thank you!!

Comment: To save everyone else a click.
    .getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(int)